# duplicate results from prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, duplicates

```
    <select>
     <?php  
       require 'dbc.php';
       $getallnature_query = "SELECT strnature, Count(*) as total FROM nature_tbl GROUP BY strnature";

     $getallnature_stmt = $db->prepare($getallnature_query);
     $getallnature_stmt->execute();
     $getallnature_stmt->bind_result($allnature,$count);
     while ($getallnature_stmt->fetch()) {
       echo "<option>$allnature </option>";
                            }
 ?>
</select>
```

question. i want to fetch all data from my nature table into an SELECT OPTION. my problem is that the result return all the duplicate records.

i used count(*) to prevent duplicate record. but still not working. can you please advice me how to merge duplicate record.

my code produce results like this

```
 <select>
     <option>Aircon unit</option>
     <option>Aircon unit</option>
     <option>Others </option>              
 </select>
```

Comment: Try using distinct - SELECT DISTINCT strnature FROM nature_tbl

Comment: i believe this is my fault. my code is working. i just type an "Aircon unit" with SPACE in database. thats why it shows both. thanks by the way DISTINCT WORK ALSO!!!  but what is the latest approach the count or distinct?

Comment: If you don't need the count then just use the sql I provided, it's a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT strnature, Count(*) as total FROM nature_tbl GROUP BY strnature;
```